# HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'testParam' is not present in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to understand how spring works.. 
I have created a form and a controller. I intentionally added a param to the method which did not match to the parameter in the request and i get an error like below.

**HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'testParam' is not present**

```
@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String processForm(@RequestParam("testParam") String title,
        Model model){

    return "formResult";
}

<form action="processForm" method="GET" >
    <input type="text" name="hello" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The requestParam which is "testParam" is mandatory here so i get this error. 
**My question is where did this error handled.** Did the dispatcherServlet checked the methods and returned 404 immediately or it tried to pass it to the controller`s method and the error happened there?

I hope the question is clear.. Thanks.

Comment: This is a generic question which can be answered checking the documentation.No point of posting it here as you don't need a solution but you need an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The controller method is not called, the handling and parameter check is done before this call. The handling flow seems like this:

> DispatcherServlet.doDispatch() ->
>   RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod() ->
>   ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest() ->
>   InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues() ->
>   HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument()

At this point is detected that the required parameters don't match and a `MissingServletRequestParameterException` is thrown.

`DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` handles the `MissingServletRequestParameterException` which results in a response with status code: Bad Request 400.